# Jquery if any element in a class meets the condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, foreach

I want to check if any element in a class meets certain conditions.
Example.

```
$(document).on('click','.modalInner_form_nav', function(){
  var input = $(this).parents('.modalInner_form').find('.validate_g'); 
  //$(input).each(function(index, element) {
    if ($(input).val() == ''){
        $(input).css('border', '#BB0000 1px solid');
        return false;
    } 
    else {
      /////////go to next///////////
      if ($(this).parents('.modalInner_form').is(':last-child')){

      } 
      else {
        $(this).parents('.modalInner_form').slideUp();
        $(this).parents('.modalInner_form').next('.modalInner_form').slideDown();
      }         
                ////////////
    }
});
```

This returns false if all input fields are empty, but if one in this class is not empty, it returns true.

Comment: Is there a problem with this code, or are you just looking to refactor it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There's a problem, if any of the ""inputs" is not empty: " if ($(input).val() == ''){", it doesn't return false. I don't want it proceeding if any of the input fields in the "validate_g" class is empty.

Comment: @ Relm share `fiddle` link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have a inner function so

```
$(document).on('click', '.modalInner_form_nav', function () {
    var $form = $(this).parents('.modalInner_form');
    var $input = $form.find('.validate_g');

    var valid = true;
    $input.each(function (index, element) {
        var $this = $(this)
        if ($this.val() == '') {
            valid = false;
            $this.css('border', '#BB0000 1px solid');
        }
    });

    if (valid) {
        if ($form.is(':last-child')) {
            //do something else
        } else {
            $form.slideUp();
            $form.next('.modalInner_form').slideDown();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: So $input === $(input); ?

Comment: @Relm yes... `var $this = $(this)` - is used to cache the reference

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what your question is, but here is a way to improve your code.

Save `$(this).parents('.modalInner_form')` in a variable instead of constantly repeating this same line of code. Then you can replace all those method calls with the variable and just call whatever functions you want on the variable.

```
var varName = $(this).parents('.modalInner_form');
varName.find('.validate_g');
...
if(varName.is(':last-child')){
...
```